InvalidModuleDescriptorException JavaFX Projekt
so I have the Problem that I havent opened my project in a while now and when I opened it and tried starting it again it threw this Error:
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: /Users/myname/Desktop/..../build/libs/fireApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package com.unknown.fireApp not found in module

Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package com.unknown.fireApp not found in module

Execution failed for task ':FireApp.main()'.

These are my Files:
build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.8.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.unknown.fireApp'
    mainClass = 'com.unknown.fireApp.FireApp'
}

javafx {
    version = '18.0.1'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.web', 'javafx.media', 'javafx.base','javafx.swing']
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.1')
    implementation('com.dlsc.formsfx:formsfx-core:11.5.0') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }
    implementation('net.synedra:validatorfx:0.3.1') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }
    implementation('org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx:12.3.1')
    implementation('org.kordamp.bootstrapfx:bootstrapfx-core:0.4.0')
    implementation('eu.hansolo:tilesfx:17.1.9') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }
    implementation('com.github.almasb:fxgl:17.1') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")

    //SQLITE
    implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.39.2.0'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.30'

    //ARGON PW HASHING
    implementation 'de.mkammerer:argon2-jvm:2.11'
    implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.12.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-params
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.10.2'

    //JAVA MAIL API
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.angus/jakarta.mail
    implementation 'org.eclipse.angus:jakarta.mail:2.0.3'

    //MOCKITO
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.11.0'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs= ["src/main/java"]
    }
        resources {
            srcDirs= ["src/main/resources"]
        }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}

the module info:
module com.unknown.fireApp {

    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.web;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires de.mkammerer.argon2.nolibs;
    requires com.almasb.fxgl.all;
    requires java.xml.crypto;
    requires java.sql;
    requires com.sun.jna;
    requires jakarta.mail;
    requires hamcrest.core;

    opens com.unknown.fireApp to javafx.controls, javafx.graphics;
    exports com.unknown.fireApp.api;
    exports com.unknown.fireApp.controller;
    exports com.unknown.fireApp.database;
    exports com.unknown.fireApp.exceptions;
    exports com.unknown.fireApp.models;
    exports com.unknown.fireApp.services;
}

My Main class:
package com.unknown.fireApp;

import com.unknown.fireApp.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import com.unknown.fireApp.services.BackupService;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Objects;

public class FireApp extends Application {

    private final BackupService backupService = new BackupService();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = new SQLiteDatabase();
        if (sqLiteDatabase.openDBConnection()) {
            sqLiteDatabase.initDB();
        }
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        backupService.createBackUpFolder();
        backupService.createAutomaticBackup();
        backupService.deleteBackupsOlderThanOneWeek();
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            try {
                Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(FireApp.class.getResource("/com.unknown.fireApp/pages/LoginPage.fxml")));
                Scene loginScene = new Scene(root,1000,700);
                root.getStylesheets().add(Objects.requireNonNull(FireApp.class.getResource("/com.unknown.fireApp/styling/LoginStyle.css")).toExternalForm());
                stage.setScene(loginScene);
                stage.setResizable(false);
                stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
                    Platform.exit();
                    System.exit(0);
                });
                stage.setTitle("Fire App");
                stage.centerOnScreen();
                stage.show();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}

Versions:
SDK: Eclipse Temurin 21.0.3
Java Version: OpenJDK 21.0.3
VM Option:
--module-path /Users/myname/Desktop/.../Tools/javafx-sdk-21.0.2/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base
I tried repulling the Project, changing different versions and tried clean building the project.
Nothing seems to work.

the 'unknown' and 'myname' are covering the real names of it

Unrelated: you have a modular app with Gradle as a build tool.  I don't use Gradle, but I think if you do and use the JavaFX plugin in it with a modular application, you don't need the JavaFX SDK and these arguments --module-path /Users/myname/Desktop/.../Tools/javafx-sdk-21.0.2/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base.
